# magento 1.8 search results filter contains all attributes

Tags: magento, search, filter, magento-1.8

On each category page, filter work correctly (can chose only parameters from products which apply to this category), but in search result page - filter consist of all attributes.

Please help me to fix problem with filter on search result page.

Comment: Please specify in your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) what you've tried.

Comment: Do you mean on category page in layered navigation you want to control the number of attributes visible?

Comment: No, I just need that after search query, filter consist of values of attributes from products in this search results (for example for query - "Oracle"  I need only "Oracle", but in the filter manufacturer - Microsoft, Adobe...") 
http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/640048/a6f6033f1d207e528a66bbe015967521

Answer (score 0):

> "Search result page - filter consist of all attributes."

I think you are referring to the "Layered Navigation" on the search results page.

You can specify which attributes appear on the search results page under the attribute settings;

- Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes.
- Select the attribute (filter) you wish to display or remove.
- Now under "**Frontend Properties**" you will see the option "**Use In Search Results Layered Navigation**"
- Adjust this value according to your requirements.